# xamarin.forms: App wont start in release on android when linker is set to NONE

Tags: xamarin.forms

I can debug my app just fine. Everything works. As soon as I set it to release, the app doesnt start. It just crashes on startup with no explaination. Setting the linker to "link assemblys and sdk" the app starts but with major bugs (texts missing, classes not loading)...

Same happens when the linker is active and the app is in debug mode.

I can only start the app in debug mode with linker set to none.

However, without alterting anything, yesterday it worked for a few builds. I could start the app in release.
Today it stopped working again.
I am completely out of ideas. The picture below is my android set up for release.

Why cant I start with no linker ? Build works fine...

[image]

*** EDIT:

I also just relised, i cannot start ANY project in releas with linker set to none. Even when I start up a new projekt from xamarin.forms, the first build in release already fails

Comment: Did you deploy the code in release mode? We can only deploy the project in debug mode using the IDE. The release mode is used for distribution. Check the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that VS has to be start as administrator if I wanna start a release build. That was never the case... But it fixes it ...